# Splitting a space-separated list of values in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing an `ID` and `Value`, where the `Value` field is a space separated list of values:

```
ID           Value   
100           A1 A2 A3     
200           B1           
300           C1 C2
```

I want to split the values string and have each one as a separate row with the ID:

```
ID          Value
100           A1           
100           A2          
100           A3           
200           B1           
300           C1          
300           C2
```

How can I do this in T-SQL?

Comment: If you struggle with English use the Google translator to ask. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is the first table the results, and the second table what you've got, or the other way around?

Comment: I've edited the question to be what I think the question is about.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing delimited values in a single column. Why don't you normalize your datamodel?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - That's what the question is about, they want to split the value list in to rows.

Comment: @Tony: yes, it is needed a normalized fashion, but apparently the OP doesn't want to *store* it that way (at least he/she didn't say that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Ah yes, I see what you mean. I thought they wanted to fix the data but looking again they could just be asking for a query to return the results in that format.

Comment: @Tony: Thank you very much :) I just joined the forum.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom `Split` function and `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT ID, Split.Item As Value
FROM dbo.TableName
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Value, ' ')as Split
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15c33/3/0)</kbd>

But it's better to normalize your database and use a separate table to link the ID with the Values.

I have used this table-valued-function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @ItemTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(250))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    --SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
     ID, 
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Value]
FROM  
(
     SELECT
        ID,
        CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Value, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS  
    FROM YourTable
) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4b11/3)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 and above has STRING_SPLIT() function to split a string into a row of substrings based on a specified separator. So, for your problem you can simply do this:

```
SELECT  ID,s.value FROM dbo.TableName t
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(t.Value, ' ') s
```